# Call regex in an Excel cell

Tags: regex, excel, excel-2007, vba

I want to extract a string from a cell using a regex match.
I can't find the excel function that does it and I'm no VBA expert either.
I use Excel 2007.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the Excel VBA code editor select Tools/References. In the picker check the latest version of Microsoft VBScript Regular Expresions.

Here is a simple user defined function to get you started. This will return "foo" if you point it at a cell with "foobar" or "fooooobar" in it.

```
Function RegExtract(contents As String)
    Dim regx As RegExp
    Set regx = New RegExp

    With regx
    .Pattern = "f[o]+"
        With .Execute(contents)
            If .Count Then RegExtract = .Item(0).Value
        End With
    End With
End Function
```

Comment: grrr so I need to write some VBA... I hoped I could avoid that.

Comment: The Tools/References is grayed out... hum. Any idea.

Comment: found my security settings where preventing. There is a small error MyExtract -> RegExtract

Answer (score 1):

Here's a function that will let you pass in a cell then any regex pattern. Use () around the part of the pattern you want the function to return.

```
Function RegexExtract(ByVal text As String, _
                      ByVal extract_what As String) As String

Dim allMatches As Object
Dim RE As Object
Set RE = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")

RE.Pattern = extract_what
RE.Global = True
Set allMatches = RE.Execute(text)
RegexExtract = allMatches.Item(0).submatches.Item(0)

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a library available in Excel's VBA system known as Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions. Once you include the library from the internal VBA 'IDE', you can create a simple macro that accepts whatever value you'd like to parse and return the result back to the caller (which can be a function call from a cell).

Comment: help me there how do you find this library & what do u call VBA IDE. I'm a real newbie in VB for Excel.

Answer (score 0):

@AndrewCowenhoven Has a good answer.  It's simple to add the Regex Library.  Just to expand this answer a little, I will add what I learned to get items within matches.

For example, I have a string like this in one cell.

doubleclick.net/activityi;u=5f2256de37ab4992927b3a0a0a34f983;u13=;u14=27.34;u16=AUD;u9=;u10=;u11=;u12=;u5=;u6=;u7=;u8=;u1=Car;u2=SEA;u3=SEA;u4=20130923%20%7C%2020130926;ord=5360319407191.128?

I only need a few sections to verify that the doubleclick tag sent to google is correct.  Using The regex shown above I have something like this.

```
Function CheckU3(contents As String)
Dim regx As RegExp
Set regx = New RegExp
Dim matches, s

With regx
.Pattern = "u3=(.*?);"
.Global = False

If regx.Test(contents) Then
    Set matches = regx.Execute(contents)
        For Each Var In matches.Item(0).SubMatches
            s = Var
        Next
End If

CheckU3 = s

End With
End Function
```

I know this could be simplified a lot, but the point is that I'm pulling the submatches using parans to get specifically what I need.

[image]